# How to Modify a Cronjob Email Subject

Tags: email, cron

I am running a half dozen different cron jobs from my hosting at Hostmonster.com.  When a cronjob has been executed I receive an email with the output of the script.

The email comes in the format of:

```
From: Cron Daemon
Subject: Cron  /ramdisk/bin/php5 -c /home5/username/scheduled/optimize_mysql.bash
```

The problem with this is that the subject of the email makes it very hard to read which cronjob the email is pertaining to.

Is there a way to modify the subject of a cronjob email so that it's easier to read?

For example:

```
From: Cron Daemon
Subject: Optimize MySQL Database
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my systems (most Debian) all output, from a script/program called as a crontab-entry, is sent by email to the `account@localhost` who initiated the cron. 
These emails have a subject like yours.

If you want to receive an email, write a script that has no output on its own. But instead put all output in a textfile.

And with

```
mail -s 'your subject' adress@where < textfile
```

you receive it the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Michèle.  I was hoping to use Hostmonster's automatic email system but looks like this will be the solution I go with.  Instead of recieving Automatic Cron emails controlled by my hosting I'll just send my own emails.

Comment: Rather than using a temp file (which creates a possible race condition) you could simply pipe the output of a command to the mail command.

Answer (score 67):

Or use the sh noop command (:)

```
0 9-17 * * 1-5    : Queue Summary; PATH=/usr/sbin qshape
```

The subject still looks kludgey, but at least it's descriptive and requires no extraneous scripts.

Comment: Now that's a hack! (I like it.)

Comment: Note that the space is important after the colon.

Comment: Is the title going to be "Queue Summary" ? And is the command "qshape" in this case?

Comment: Looks like qshape is a postfix command. My unix machine uses "mail" command. But is the qshape command relevant here?

Comment: This seemed like a great tip, but I just cannot get it to work. The command following the noop command is never executed.

Comment: Tried this on CentOS release 6.8 and on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and it worked like a charm. Accepted answer is probably better architecturally, but this gets the job done and doesn't require you to wrap your scripts. I would also highly suggest looking at `qshape 2>&1 | mail -s "Queue Summary" -E` which sends an email only if it's non-zero length. (`mail -E`) Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/how-to-pipe-output-from-one-process-to-another-but-only-execute-if-the-first-has

Comment: FYI, the subject of the email will be `Queue Summary; PATH=/usr/sbin qshape`

Comment: I would like to sneak in some end-of-string character after `Quere Summary` to shorten the subject line. I have tried `\u0003`, that is, `=?UTF-8?Q?=03?=`, but that is shown as a space in the email header when received. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 28):

Pipe your cron job output to mail directly, and then you can fill in the subject line.  the `2>&1` syntax sends any error output which would otherwise disappear.

```
mycmd 2>&1 | mail -s "mycmd output" myname
```

Comment: I'm doing this, but internal to the script cron calls because I want the subject to reflect the success or failure of the script being run.

Comment: With GNU mail I added the option `-r, --return-address=ADDRESS` to avoid the following error with the SMTP server : `Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command)`.

Answer (score 14):

Take over crond's responsibility for sending command output (or not if there isn't any) by piping output and stderr into 'mailx -E'. For example:

```
0 * * * * your-command 2>&1 | mailx -E -s "Descriptive Subject" $LOGNAME
```

Mailx's '-E' option is nice because, just like crond itself, it won't send a mail if there isn't any output to send.

Comment: What is the $LOGNAME variable here?

Comment: Is there a way to email only when the exit code of the command is non zero?

Comment: @PratikKhadloya, from crontab(5):

`Several  environment  variables  are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner. PATH is set to "/usr/bin:/bin".  HOME, SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME is the user that the job is running from, and may not be changed.`

Comment: There are multiple `mailx` implementations; only some of them offer this `-E` option. On Ubuntu you want the `bsd-mailx` or `heirloom-mailx` packages; the `mailutils` package contains a Gnu `mailx` command with a different `-E`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to write a shell script with the subject line you want that calls the right command. In your example, this would be:

```
#Optimize_MySQL_Database.sh

/ramdisk/bin/php5 -c /home5/username/scheduled/optimize_mysql.bash
```

You can include your bin directory in the path by setting it in the crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS--In the command line implement the following code---

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /path /hostname/foldername/Page-You-want-to-execute \
   | **mail -s "*SUBJECT*" YOUR@MAIL.COM.**
```

- This is just a referance to guide You